# 78 TransactionManagers, find by JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, maven

Moving from Software as a Service to Platform as a Service, I need to migrate about 78 databases. All have a similar structure. I created a `maven` project having 87 modules having only entities.

While migrating used values in table "salutation" to only one table, I need to walk through the entity-relations of those 78 projects.

Unfortunately, the walk-through requires a transactionmanager, but only one can be activated per method using

```
@Autowired
private final CustomerRepository58 cr58 = null;

@Autowired
private final CustomerRepository59 cr59 = null;

@Transactional("database-58")
public void migrate(){
```

I can not walk from a customer in `cr59` to its salutation also all other 77 datasources can not do that.

How to switch the `TransactionManager` programmatically?